# How to create/handle a custom string filter on active admin outside of my model scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I use ransack to handle basic custom filter but I don't know how to handle a active admin string filter that has options like (Contains, Equals, Starts with, Ends with).

this is what I've done so far but it results to an error when hitting the filter button.

Error:

> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~*
>   integer LINE 1: ...unt_column FROM "payments" WHERE ("payments"."id"
>   ILIKE 0) L...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might
>   need to add explicit type casts. : SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM
>   (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "payments" WHERE ("payments"."id"
>   ILIKE 0) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count

Ransacker:

```
ransacker :part_number,
  formatter: proc { |part_no|
    tire_ids = Tire.where("part_number ILIKE ?", "%#{part_no}%").pluck(:id).flatten.uniq
    owner_ids = ShoppingCartItem.where(item_id: tire_ids).pluck(:owner_id).flatten.uniq
    shopping_cart_ids = ShoppingCart.where(id: owner_ids).pluck(:id).flatten.uniq
    results = Payment.where(shopping_cart_id: shopping_cart_ids)
    results = results.present? ? results.map(&:id) : [0]
  }, splat_params: true do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
end
```

Filter:
[Active admin String Filter Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5qTX.png)